# How to define a namespace in XML?

Tags: xml, namespaces

I use Eclipse for J2EE programming. In the HTML code, we can use the JSF (or any other) namespaces using the xmlns attribute. Once you specify a namespace using the xmlns attribute, say `xmlns:f="..."`, and when you type `<f:` you automatically get the tags under the `f` namespace.

I want to define my own namespace with a list of tags and attributes for every tag.

How do I define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just the namespace, all you need to do is pick a URL that is guaranteed to be unique and use it as your namespace. A common convention is to use a URL under a domain you own, e.g. http://www.idiotguy.com/my-super-xml-namespace.

The namespace by itself doesn't say anything about the document structure though; for that, you need to write a DTD or XSD and link your document to it.

Comment: You don't have to pick a URL. Any URI will do, so another common convention is to use a URN.