# PHP and parsing an xml with a namespace

Tags: php, xml

I try to parse an xml with a namespace:

```
<?php
$myxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- This is my xml --><aa:b></aa:b>';
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->loadXML($myxml); //this is line 4
```

How to parse it that I don't get error:

```
Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Namespace prefix aa on b is not defined in Entity, line: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\xmlparse.php
```

Has the DOMDocument a such property?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a namespace in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661381/how-to-define-a-namespace-in-xml)

Comment: The parser is correct. The namespace `aa` is not defined. try adding `xmlns:aa="my.namespace.com"` to the root element of the XML...