# What is an XML "namespace" and how is it defined?

Tags: .net, xml

I need to update our application to support uploading XML documents, instead of just CSV's. So I'm trying to first validate that the file the user uploads contains all of the required nodes.

I was reading this guide on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037.aspx) but I'm unclear on the third command in this block of code:

```
string xsdMarkup =
    @"<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
        <xsd:element name='Root'>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name='Child1' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>
                    <xsd:element name='Child2' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>";

XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecy9csyh.aspx) for an `XmlSchemaSet` object defines the first string as so:

> targetNamespace
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The schema targetNamespace property, or null to use the targetNamespace specified in the schema.

Then down in the remarks, it has this note about that parameter:

> **The Add method of the XmlSchemaSet has the ability to use the target namespace defined in a schema**, rather than requiring the target namespace be specified as a parameter when the Add method is called. **Specifying null or String.Empty to the Add method instructs the XmlSchemaSet to use the target namespace defined in the schema**. For an example of this behavior, see the [Add(string targetNamespace, string schemaUri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hh8b082.aspx) method.

But I don't understand exactly what is meant by the parts I bolded.

What is meant by a namespace in reference to XML? I know what it means from a code perspective, but not XML. Additionally, in the code snippet I posted above from MSDN, where is this namespace defined? Since it's passing an empty string to the `Add` method, that means it's referencing the target namespace defined in the schema, which must be that first `xmlns` node in their `xsdMarkup` string. But I still don't understand.

I don't really "understand" what I'm looking at, or how I should configure *my* schema to ensure the XML they've uploaded to my application has all the needed nodes. I saw [this SO question on how to define an XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661381/how-to-define-a-namespace-in-xml) but that doesn't help me.